# Is there a name for a logarithm with a mantissa of zero?

Tags: terminology

Not a math guy, just asking out of curiosity.

I recently came to understand that a logarithm's integer and fraction parts are respectively called the characteristic and the mantissa (if that's wrong then feel free to smash me to pieces).

Right now I need to do some work with base ten log results and I need to do something depending on if the resulting logarithm has a mantissa of zero:

```
log10(0.1) = -1
log10(0.2) = -0.698...
...
log10(1) = 0
```

In the expressions above, is there a specific terminology to differentiate results like -1 and 0 from other logarithms?

Comment: If the number you are taking a log of is an integer power of the base, (in the case of $10$, any number of the form $10^{k}$, i.e $0.1 = 10^{-1}$, $1 = 10^0$, will return the integer $k$ when you take the base 10 $\log$. That is to say $\log_{10}(10^k) = k$. Thus, when $k$ is an integera, your mantissa will be $0$ (i.e you will have no fractional part).

Comment: @rubikscube09 And is there a name for those? Or they're not considered any more special than other common logarithms?

Comment: Just powers of 10? I'm not sure how much more specific I can be. I guess to answer your question, no not really. Unless I am misunderstanding what you may be trying to ask.

Comment: Are you asking for a term when output of the logarithm is an integer?  Those just represent when the input is a perfect power of the base.  And 0, 1,-1 represent, of course, 1, the base, and the reciprical of the base.

Comment: @fleablood So is "perfect power" the correct terminology?

Comment: @rubikscube09 I don't think you are misunderstanding. This is about terminology. Like 2 can be called a number, it also can be called an integer, an even number, a prime number and a square root when it is the result of √4. There might simply not be any specific designation for powers of ten that are "perfect". Hence, that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: " So is "perfect power" the correct terminology?"  I don't have any freaking idea.  Why would anyone need terminology for this?

Comment: @fleablood I don't mean to disgress but why is there terminology for anything? :-) A logarithm that also happens to be an integer is also the result of an integer power of the smallest possible figure that can be expressed by a finite number of digits (10 for 2, 100 for 3, etc...). Given how large the math glossary is, it didn't seem unreasonable to believe there would also be a way to designate a logarithm that also is a shift to an additionnal digit...